# Can I use PhantomJS to take a screenshot of my Cordova app?

Tags: cordova, phantomjs

My Cordova app (Ionic Framework) displays graphs using nvd3.  I'd like to be able to generate copies of these graphs as PNG files for saving/sharing.  I've seen posts that seem to indicate that PhantomJS can be used for similar tasks in a Cordova app, but there [don't seem to be any plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=phantom).  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

PhantomJS has nice, clear instructions for selecting a [viewport size](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/viewport-size.html), [scroll position](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/scroll-position.html), then [rendering](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) the screen.  So it seems to have the features that I would need.  I also spotted [cordova-screenshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/com.darktalker.cordova.screenshot) as an alternative, though it seems to be limited to a full screen image.

Edit: [SVG.toDataUrl](https://github.com/sampumon/SVG.toDataURL) might get me what I need as well.  I'll try that out.

Comment: PhantomJS is a browser that acesses websites by URL. Can your application be exposed on a host on a port?

Comment: It might be run on localhost from within the device environment.  I guess I'd need to double check how Cordova handles that.

Comment: Well then you would just access http://deviceurl/:port in PhantomJS script and do screenshots.

Comment: I guess my question, then, is "how do I trigger PhantomJS from within the app?"